# Which of the following might turn NaNO2 into N2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

> Which of the following might turn $\ce{NaNO2}$ into $\ce{N2}$?
>
> A. $\ce{NaCl}$ B. $\ce{NH4Cl}$ C. $\ce{HNO3}$ D. $\ce{H2SO4}$

The answer is B and we have
$$\ce{NH4Cl + NaNO2 = NaCl + 2H2O + N2↑}.\tag1$$

How can we solve this multiple choice question without knowing $(1)$?

Comment: To get elemental nitrogen for Sodium Nitrite you need to reduce the nitrite. Only B contains a reasonable reducing agent, the ammonium ion. So it must be B.

Comment: The ability to answer questions requires knowledge of facts or principles leading to them.  That is valid in chemistry, in science and all human activities.

Comment: You can't. Or rather, you can conclude that (B) is the only compound here containing N in negative oxidation state, which may lead to some beneficial consequences... but that very way of thinking only develops when you know a good deal of chemistry, and in particular a great many reactions, most likely including (1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get N<sub>2</sub> from NaNO<sub>2</sub>, NaNO<sub>2</sub> must be reduced right, So we need a reducing agent which oxidizes itself and would reduce NaNO<sub>2</sub>

Now look at the options

Let's see HNO<sub>3</sub>, the oxidation state of Nitrogen is already $+5$ and since $+5$ is the highest oxidation state, there is no chance of HNO<sub>3</sub> to get oxidized further. So it cannot reduce NaNO<sub>2</sub>.

The same analogy goes with H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> ( S is already in its highest oxidation state $+6$ ), Also Na+ cannot get oxidised further also.

NH<sub>4</sub>Cl can get oxidised as N's oxidation state is in $-3$, This could be a good way to guess the answer for a multiple choice question, You will also not able to guess between two reducing agents, you should know the reaction anyways.

But as Poutnik did state in comments - "The ability to answer questions requires knowledge of facts or principles leading to them. That is valid in chemistry, in science and all human activities", You would need the knowledge of the reaction to answer such questions.

Comment: Wonderful idea! The problem was probably intended to examine knowledge about redox, instead of any particular reaction.